# Hide cursor in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, mouse

I am not using a mouse in the installation of the Raspberry Pi.  However, the cursor shows up right in the center of the screen.  Ideally I would like it to be there for 5 seconds, then disappear.  Or have it only appear when the mouse is plugged in.

I have poked around a bit and have not found a way to make it time out.  Is there such a setting in Raspbian?

Comment: This works as described. Run as shell command, add "&" to end of command to release shell (which will also allow the exec to run free, must end with 'kill' command thereafter). Nice and simple. Day 5 with RPi, going well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an application for this called `unclutter`. It will hide your mouse after a set time if there is no activity.

I'm not a Debian user, but it looks to me as if it is on the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install unclutter
```

If not then you can get the source from [their website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unclutter/) and build it yourself.